conflicting requests: OpenDkim / Rocky Linux
Im trying to install opendkim on Rocky Linux 9.4 but im getting this error:
[soac@domain ~]$ sudo dnf repolist
repo id                                                                        repo name
Webmin                                                                         Webmin Distribution Neutral
appstream                                                                      Rocky Linux 9 - AppStream
baseos                                                                         Rocky Linux 9 - BaseOS
epel                                                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64
epel-cisco-openh264                                                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64
extras                                                                         Rocky Linux 9 - Extras
pgAdmin4                                                                       pgadmin4
pgdg-common                                                                    PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 9 - x86_64
pgdg12                                                                         PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 9 - x86_64
pgdg13                                                                         PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 9 - x86_64
pgdg14                                                                         PostgreSQL 14 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 9 - x86_64
pgdg15                                                                         PostgreSQL 15 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 9 - x86_64
pgdg16                                                                         PostgreSQL 16 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 9 - x86_64
remi-modular                                                                   Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64
remi-safe                                                                      Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64
[soac@domain ~]$ sudo dnf install opendkim
Last metadata expiration check: 0:26:36 ago on Sun 30 Jun 2024 03:11:54 PM CEST.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libmilter.so.1.0()(64bit) needed by opendkim-2.11.0-0.36.el9.x86_64 from epel
  - nothing provides libmemcached.so.11()(64bit) needed by opendkim-2.11.0-0.36.el9.x86_64 from epel
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)


I understand that --skip-broken could be a solution but Im not sure if is the right solution.

You can use
dnf config-manager --set-enabled crb

You need to enable CRB repository via "/usr/bin/crb enable" command

I fixed the issue installing manually the dependencies.
